# Why a "plan B" and not a "B plan"?

Tags: expressions

If I were an Englishman I wouldn't prefer a "B plan" to a "plan B".
Why is it so?

Comment: Because "B" here is used as an ordinal value; it's effectively the same as "plan #2". We say "plan B" for the same reason we say "plan 2", and we don't say "B plan" for the same reasons we don't say "2 plan". Just in case the thought got into your head, the "B" doesn't stand for "backup", it's simply the 2nd letter of the alphabet. The original, primary plan would be "Plan A".

Comment: Also, I can see ambiguity creeping in. E.g. "A plan did not work" does that mean simply that 'a plan did not work' or the first plan did not work?

Comment: Because "plan B" is an idiom.

Comment: No, if you were an Englishman, you would prefer a _plan B_ to a _B plan_, because a _B plan_ would be something entirely different. One thing is that it’s just idiomatic—quite another is that your question is based on a false premise. I see no reason why _B plan_ should be any more logical than _plan B_. As @Dan says, enumerations like this are nearly always postpositioned in English.

Comment: Of course, it's the "A Team".

Comment: @HotLicks The key there is the *the*. It's always *the A Team*, not just "A Team".

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Thank you, I reformulated the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While there is no "rule", one can obtain some guidance from observing that, in "plan B", we are not speaking of a plan named "B", but rather simply the second plan in a succession, using the alphabet to annotate them.  Had we wanted to *name* the plan we *might* have used "B Plan" (though the specific words "plan B" are so idiomatic that this one isn't going to sound right).

Consider "The A Team" (the *name* of a team) vs "team A" (simply the first team in a enumerated series).

Comment: In "HMS Endeavour" the ship has a name, is that also idiomatic?

Comment: @Emmanuel - Yes, it's the same format.